# Does taking Magic Initiate and choosing Wizard give you a spellbook you can keep adding new spells to?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

If I build a Bard he can't learn any new spells outside his class. The wizard however can learn any spell he gets in his/her spell book. If the Bard takes the feat **Magic Initiate** and chooses wizard, then would he have a spellbook that he could keep adding spells to?

Comment: Hi Travis, welcome to Stack RPG! I added DND-5E as a tag, see above, and made the question a little less "chatty."

Comment: Do you own the Players Handbook?

Answer (score 14):

## No, but...

**Magic Initiate** does not provide a spell book. If it did, it would say so.

If you are interested in having a bard that knows a greater variety of spells, consider the feat **Ritual Caster**, which does provide a ritual book, and lets you add ritual spells to it that you may find during your adventures.

Be aware you can only cast these spells as rituals, however. They would be a separate *batch* of spells from your Bard spells.

A spell book is a unique feature of the Wizard class in 5e. Be aware though, it’s not correct that a wizard can learn *any* spell. They can (generally) only add spells from the wizard spell list to their books.

Also note, a Bard’s 10th level power, Magical Secrets, will grant you 2 spells that do not need to be on the Bard spell list.

#### Tip about the different spellcasters

The rules for spellcasting for different classes can be confusing at first. There is no table, for instance, where you can compare what classes get what features. When you read the rules, understand the class gets, or the feat provides, exactly what the rules say, nothing more. It might feel like it would be sensible if a wizardly magic initiate got a spellbook, but the rules don't say that, and you should not assume it's implied.

Comment: Also worth noting that if a bard takes Magic Initiate (Bard), you can use your regular bard spell slots to cast the spell you get from Magic Initiate, in addition to the usual once-per-long-rest usage.

Comment: it is also worth nothing the oddities with multiclassing.  You still prepare spells for each class, however, you have available to you a "joint pool" of spell slots, some of which can be higher level than you can cast (but can be used to enhance the effects of spells that can be cast at higher level)